rails turbo stimulus dependent select
I'm trying to work with Rails, turbo, stimulus. My cases is dependent select.
Flow:
When Item Type select box was clicked, its should update the data of Asset Item Type select box. This is my code, and its not work.
controller:
 def asset_item_types
      @target = params[:target]
      @asset_item_types = AssetType.find_by_name(params[:item_type].downcase)&.asset_item_types || []
      respond_to do |format|
        format.turbo_stream
      end
    end

turbo_stream (asset_item_types.turbo_stream.erb)
<%= turbo_stream.update @target do %>
    <%= options_for_select(@asset_item_types.map { |item_type| [item_type.name.capitalize, item_type.id] }) %>
<% end %>

html.erb (this is where the dependent select invoked)
<div class="bg-slate-50 rounded-lg mt-4 mb-4 p-4 hidden" data-toggle-target="toggle">
  <%= search_form_for [:admin, @q], url: admin_asset_models_path, data: { 
    controller: "filters",
    turbo_frame: :table,
    turbo_action: "advance",
    filters_delay_value: 200,
    filters_table_outlet: ".table-asset_model"
  } do |f| %>

    <div class="md:flex gap-2">
      <div class="w-full mb-2">
        <%= f.label "#{t('activerecord.attributes.asset_model.name')}", class: "block text-gray-700" %>
        <%= f.search_field :name_cont, data: { action: "filters#submit" }, class: "w-full border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 mt-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300" %>
      </div>

      <div class="w-full mb-2">
        <%= f.label "#{t('activerecord.models.brand')}", class: "block text-gray-700" %>
        <%= f.select :brand_name_cont,
          Brand.pluck(:name).map { |name| [name.capitalize]},
          {include_blank: t("custom.label.all", model: t("activerecord.models.brand")).capitalize},
          data: { action: "filters#submit", controller: "slim" },
          class: "w-full border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 mt-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300"
        %>
      </div>

      <div data-controller="slim">
        <div class="w-full mb-2">
          <%= f.label "#{t('activerecord.models.asset_type')}", class: "block text-gray-700" %>
          <%= f.select :asset_type_name_cont,
            AssetType.pluck(:name).map { |name| [name.capitalize]},
            {include_blank: t("custom.label.all", model: t("activerecord.models.asset_type")).capitalize},
            data: { action: "change->slim#change click->filters#submit" },
            class: "w-full border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 mt-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300"
          %>
        </div>

        <div class="w-full mb-2">
          <%= f.label "#{t('activerecord.models.asset_item_type')}", class: "block text-gray-700" %>
          <%= f.select :asset_item_type_name_cont,
            @asset_item_types.pluck(:name).map { |name| [name.capitalize]},
            {include_blank: t("custom.label.all", model: t("activerecord.models.asset_item_type")).capitalize},
            data: { slim_target: "dependentSelect" },
            class: "w-full border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 mt-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300"
          %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  <% end %>

</div>

@asset_item_types just an instance variable invoked using before_action to initialize default value.
My stimulus:
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import SlimSelect from "slim-select";
import { get } from "@rails/request.js"

// Connects to data-controller="slim"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["dependentSelect"]

  connect() {
    this.select = new SlimSelect({
      select: this.element
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.select.destroy();
  }


  change(event) {
    let value = event.target.selectedOptions[0].value;
    let target = this.dependentSelectTarget.id;

    get(`asset_models/asset_item_types?target=${target}&item_type=${value}`, {
      responseKind: 'turbo-stream'
    })
  }
}

Thats all.
I have tried the code above
